# Компилятор С++ под виндовс 7

Tags: компилятор, c++

Очень бы хотелось компилятор, показывающий какие ошибки я сделала, если такие есть.   Посоветуйте новичку

Comment: Мне интересно, где вы нашли компилятор, который _не_ показывает ошибки. Хотя, конечно, смотря что называть ошибками.

Comment: Не я нашла, мне дали и сказали, что хороший.

Comment: @Solly и как он называется?

Comment: Не помню, уже удалила. Он вроде похож на DEVCPP, опять-таки, как мне сказали.

Answer (score 3):

Для новичка, наверное, лучше сразу хорошая интегрированная среда разработки (IDE):

[Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 для Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=40787)

Comment: @DreamChild
Не без этого) Но не чересчур, это же IDE, а не текстовый редактор. Бегает она шустро для своего функционала. На крайний случай - командную строка + блокнот. QtCreator + MinGW - реальная альтернатива, на мой взгляд. Но такого шикарного дебаггера, как в MSVS, нет нигде! =) А я стараюсь всех новичков сразу учить им пользоваться, ибо это важная софтина для C/C++ и здорово помогает в учебных экспериментах.

Comment: @Free_ze речь тут вот о чем - для студента/новичка всё же логичнее изучать сам С++ без каких-либо сторонних функций, макросов, библиотечек и прочего (а все это счастье вроде того же stdafx.h поставляется вместе с VC++ и несколько сбивает с толку новичка, заранее направляя его по соответствующей колее). Кроме того, размер дистрибутива такой IDE для начинающего в полгигабайта - это перебор тащемта. А вот насчет дебаггера согласен - они у MS-овских инструментов более чем классные

Comment: @DreamChild
Ну не правда же) Никто в тонкости MS-расширений лезть не обязан. Когда я учился, у нас в группе было особым понтом писать кросскомпиляторный код и по стандарту.
Предкомпилированные заголовки при создании пустого консольного проекта по дефолту отключены, проблем не будет. А даже если будут, комьюнити просто огромное, помогут)
А иде новичку на спине носить? Не вижу в размере проблемы, ну честно. Зачем загонять себя в рамки ущербных, непопулярных инструментов просто из-за того, что там нет кнопкок с неизвестным тебе назначением? Все знание приходит с опытом и гуглингом.

Comment: @Free_ze а вот и правда. Создает, скажем, новичок HelloWorld в VC, видит, что к нему прикрепляется некий stdfax.h, убрав который он получает некие невнятные ошибки (когда во всех примерах никаких stdfax нет). Или дурацкие ошибки, когда нельзя использовать scanf, а вместо него следует юзать scanf_s. Скопировал новичок откуда-то код, а затем либо вынужден приводить его в порядок, заставляя компилятор это сожрать либо искать, как эту привередливость отключить. И таких примеров может быть много. Это изначально создает неудобства (где-то мелкие, где-то не очень), которые любви к языку не добавляют

Comment: а что касается размера, то софтина меньшего размера всегда предпочтительнее аналогичной, но большего. Конечно, таскать ее на себе не придется, однако есть люди, для которых выкачать 50 мб куда предпочтительнее, чем в 10 раз больше. Не у всех же есть быстрый интернет. Да и установка в случае с маленькими IDE куда быстрее

Comment: @DreamChild Так. Еще раз. Если создавать пустой проект, никаких предкомпилированных заголовков с их stdafx`ами не появится. Рекомендации MSовских функций - это всегда ворнинги, никогда не ошибки. А ну кого нет быстрого интернета, тому не повезло =) Остальным-то за что страдать? Да и вообще, программирование - спорт для любознательных.

Comment: ок смотрите: 

1) создаем пустой консольный проект

![alt text][1]
![alt text][2]

2) на всякий случай даже уберем галочку "precompiled header"

![alt text][3]

3) вуаля: ![alt text][4]

А что касается scanf_s - [вот вопрос][5] на ту же тему


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/rV9NiT1.png
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/ERgI2rM.png
  [3]: http://i.imgur.com/zCpR0zO.png
  [4]: http://i.imgur.com/GrqLro3.png
  [5]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/270343/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-scanf-%D0%B2-vs2012

Comment: @Free_ze а что, в MSVS действительно уникальный дебаггер? И даже лучше, чем gdb? И даже лучше, чем emacs+gdb? С чего бы это?

Comment: @DreamChild Галка "empty project" принципиально была проигнорирована?)

Comment: @alexlz Новичек и emacs? Как же вам людей не жалко..(
Да, студийный дебаггер лучше) Хотя бы тем, что он тесно связан с ней.

UPD: Комменты кончились) Ладно, это уж придирки всё) Даже если неофит не будет отрываться от учебника, эту заготовку он сам напишет.

Comment: @Free_ze во-первых, без вашего комментария я даже не обратил на нее внимание (причем вроде не первый год замужем как говорится. Чего уж там про совсем новичков?)
во-вторых, при выборе этой галки я получаю абсолютно пустой проект. Даже без такой заготовки:

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() 
    {
        return 0;
    }

это уж совсем минимализм. К чему совсем новичку все эти лишние телодвижения, когда огроменная тяжеловесная IDE не способна сгенерировать ему правильный шаблон консольного приложения? Тут куда проще вообще программировать на ideone каком-нибудь

Comment: Небольшая провокация.

А может новичку-то лучше будет сначала вообще без IDE поучиться?

man, ls, find, grep, emacs, make, gcc, gdb, nm, od (или hd), sh... + любимый браузер.

Учись, комбинируй в удобных для  себя сочетаниях.

Comment: >А может новичку-то лучше будет сначала вообще без IDE поучиться? 

@avp может быть. Только захочет ли он? Новичков нужно привлекать, а не отпугивать

Comment: @DreamChild "Тут опять пошла морока про коварный зарубеж". C++, с моей точки зрения, далеко не лучший выбор для первого языка. А уж тех, кто немного разобрался в программировании, такие мелочи вроде не должны пугать. Ну а если первый -- то увы. Тогда "злобного буратино" надо искать в другом месте.

@Free_ze а чем так страшен emacs? Там можно работать не зная e-lisp. И уж всяко лучше notbook'а. А вот я вспомнил свой опыт с VS6 -- цензурных слов нет (проблема была с сообщениями компилятора. Длина около 1000 символов, vs строку переносит после половины и в окошке я вижу две 1/6 -- 1ю и 4ю).

Comment: @alexlz не очень понял, что за "коварный зарубеж"? А что касается первого языка, то довольно распространена практика, когда в качестве первого используют Си, а затем переходят на плюсы

Comment: @DreamChild про зарубеж и мороку --  http://www.kulichki.com/vv/pesni/ya-vchera-zakonchil-kovku.html

А насчёт практики -- ну что ж. Хорошо хоть негров не линчуют. А вот C/С++ и программирование в системе MS DOS на языке ассемблера -- эт' обязательно. Болонская система по выращиванию болонок-бакалавров... Свидетели иЕГЭовы...

Comment: @alexlz извините, но я вас решительно не понимаю. Речь вроде бы идет о С++ компиляторах и IDE. При чем тут вообще негры, какие-то поездки за рубеж, бакалавриат, болонки и прочее?

Comment: @DreamChild поднимаются вопросы, которые обсуждаются регулярно и без результата. К вопросу ТС @Solly отношения не имеющие (какой у неё компилятор? Что значит "не показывает ошибки"?) Т.е. идёт трёп ни о чём. Тут можно и Высоцкого вспомнить, и негров -- толку от этого будет не больше, но и не сильно меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Новичку больше, чем за глаза хватит маленькой шустрой IDE [CodeBlocks](http://prdownload.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe). Она хороша своей легковесностью, быстротой и простотой установки, поставляемым в комплекте компилятором (MinGW) и наличием всех необходимых инструментов для удобной работы для новичка

Answer (score 1):

[@Solly](/users/17353/solly) а вы учите С++ для себя или для оценки по учёбе?

---

если для оценки то смело ставьте IDE (интегрированную среду разработчика) вроде Microsoft Visual Studio или на мой взгляд более удобную QtCreator или любую другую за исключением "C++ Builder" и "RAD Studio" (когда-нибудь вы начнёте делать графические приложения и возможно вас пошлют в эти две среды и тогда они научат вас мышекликательному программированию, бесполезному и крайне ущербному)

в интернете вы найдёте кучу примеров с картинками и без труда сможете получить оценку, но "**настоящих**" знаний С++  у вас не будет!

---

совсем другое дело обстоит если вы хотите программировать для себя или если вы хотите зарабатывать программированием.
второй вариант крайне сложен особенно новичку в нём вам надо отдельно создавать файлы c,h,cpp,hpp (файлы исходного кода программы), вам отдельно нужно будет запускать всё это счастье через консоль, вам вручную придётся писать make-файлы и вам придётся больше читать про сборку программ и того почему "С++ != С"

в этом случае вы также можете писать исходный код в любом "умном" текстовом редакторе даже если он встроен в IDE (например писать в Visual Studio а компилить в ручную)

и только разобравшись во всём этом вы по настоящему сможете называть  себя С++ программистом

Comment: Зачем так усложнять? Может стоит поэтапно, сначала выучить основы, чтобы знать ЗАЧЕМ нужна вся эта ручная рутина с компиляцией, линковкой. А то так звучит, будто начав с IDE, путь в профессию будет заказан) Программисты - это люди, которым все это и так интересно, а не те, кто бегают обосраными, пытаясь "создать свою игру".

Comment: Во-первых, вы уверены, что путь к тому, чтобы "по настоящему называть себя С++ программистом" лежит всего лишь через умение "отдельно создавать файлы c,h,cpp,hpp" и "вручную писать make-файлы"? Думаю, куда важнее другие аспекты языка, которых очень много

Во-вторых, вышеперечисленные умения, конечно, небесполезны, но и обязательными их не назовёшь. Соглашаясь с @Free_ze не вижу ничего ужасного в том, чтобы начать именно с IDE, а не голого компилятора

В-третьих, если уж человек ищет компилятор именно "для оценки по учёбе", то для него нет ничего ужасного и в "мышекликательном программировании

Comment: @DreamChild Я так полагаю, что имелось в виду желание провести новичка сразу по всем граблям, чтоб потом легче жилось. Однако, высок шанс действительно так запутать или отпугнуть. Примерно так работает система высшего образования: дать знания "на вырост", возможно с неполным осознанием, но потом всю эту информацию по обрывкам будет куда легче восстановить. Но это же хобби, здесь очень важна мотивация. А какая ж будет мораль, когда, чтобы запустить хелловорд, нужно потрахаться сначала с компилятором, потом с компоновщиком, или вообще c CMake`ом? (утрирую, конечно)

Comment: @Free_ze согласен, подобные манипуляции у многих отобьют любое желание программировать

Comment: Для себя. А что такое IDE и чем оно отличается от компилятора?

Comment: @Solly IDE - это итегрированная среда разработки, по сути - тулкит, с помощью которого можно разрабатывать программы. Инструмент "все в одном". Как правило, состоит из текстового редактора, компилятора, компановщика, отладчика и других безумно необходимых штук.По сути, всем этим можно пользоваться вразнобой: компилировать исходники компилятором, получая объектные модули, потом компоновщиком их собирать в единый исполняемый файл. Все эти процессы можно немного автоматизировать, если использовать системы сборки вроде CMake, которым можно писать сценарии в, так называемых, make-файлах.

Comment: @Solly Ну и потом можно программу отлаживать, подключаясь к ней отладчиком, например - GDB. Ну и сам исходный текст писать в стороннем текстовом редакторе. IDE, по сути, это надстройка еще и над системой сборки, т.к. основываясь на настройках проекта, файлах, включенных в проект, она
управляет всеми этими стадиями.

Так что компилятор - это одна из составляющих IDE.

Comment: @Free_ze вспомнил одну старую ссылку http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/doesvisualstudiorotthemind.html

Answer (score 0):

Когда я начинаю изучать C++ то использовал Microsoft Visual C++ и по книге все действия осуществлялись именно в нём. Советую!

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator + MinGW. Этого будет достаточно.

Comment: А как там с дебаггером дела из коробки?

Comment: Проблем не замечал, работает достаточно хорошо